# Find customers that have both of the specified values in a column

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table called `CustomerTable`:

Customer Table

[image]

I would like to find the customers that have both `House` and `Apartment` services present. Ideally I should have Peter and Amanda returned in my results.

I am trying the below query but it is returning all customers that either have house or apartment. Please help

```
select * 
from CustomerTable 
where SERVICE in ('House', 'Apartment')
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
select customer_name
from CustomerTable
where SERVICE in ('House', 'Apartment')
group by customer_name
having min(service) <> max(service);
```

Comment: I have put in the values just like depicted above and also added the group by function but it somehow returning a blank result. Any modifications required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HAVING clause like so:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM CustomerTable
WHERE SERVICE IN ('House', 'Apartment')
GROUP BY CUSTOMERNAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SERVICE) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerTable(
  CustomerName VARCHAR(45),
  Service VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO CustomerTable VALUES
('Mark', 'House'),
('Mark', 'Condo'),
('Ashley', 'Condo'),
('John', 'House'),
('John', 'Condo'),
('David', 'House'),
('Peter', 'House'),
('Peter', 'Apartment'),
('Peter', 'Condo'),
('Amanda', 'House'),
('Amanda', 'Apartment');

SELECT    CustomerName
FROM      CustomerTable
WHERE     Service IN ('House', 'Apartment')
GROUP BY  CustomerName
HAVING    MAX(Service) != MIN(Service);
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+--------------+
|    | CustomerName |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Amanda       |
|  2 | Peter        |
+----+--------------+
```